# How do i create password protected pdf file in vb6.0?

Tags: pdf, vb6, ms-word, password-protection, office-automation

I am working with VB6.0 and I have a requirenment to create a password protected pdf file in vb6.0.

I have successfully created a PDF file but how do i make it password protected?

**Edit:**
I am creating my PDF file by exporting from word file using this code.

```
objWordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _ 
   sDests & sDestsPDFFile, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _ 
   OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
   wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
   IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _ 
   wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _ 
   True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

Comment: How did you create the PDF? Are you using a PDF library? If yes, then what's the name of the library?

Comment: No i am not using any library. I am creating my PDF file by exporting from word file using this code.
objWordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        sDests & sDestsPDFFile, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
        wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
        IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
        wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
        True, UseISO19005_1:=False

Comment: So nothing strictly to do with VB6? I've added the Word and Office automation tags so it can be seen by people that know about Word and Office automation.

Comment: Thanks Deanna, hope that Word and office automation tags will help. but is there any other way? is it possible to create password protected pdf file using visual basic?

Answer (score 0):

`ExportAsFixedFormat` has no mechanism for password protecting a PDF. You need to use some other tool.

**EDIT**

To address your follow-on question, there are a number of tools that can add password protection to existing documents.  My company, Atalasoft, has [a product](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotpdf/) that will do that too (although it is likely a very big hammer for this very small nail).  The code to password protect an existing PDF looks like this:

```
public static void SetPdfPassword(Stream inStm, Stream outStm, string userpassword, string ownerpassword)
{
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(inStm);
    doc.Save(userpassword, ownerpassword, outStm);
}
```

Our tools, however, do not integrate into Word.

Comment: After Exporting to PDF, is there any way to set the password to existing pdf? or how can i create password protected pdf file from my word file?